# Windows Media Player doesn't add files to the library automatically except for playlists

Tags: windows-media-player

Recently I've moved the music from a portable drive to the hard drive. Ever since then Windows Media Player can't detect the files in the music folder no matter what I do. I tried to delete the databases of media player in AppData, I tried resetting the settings by running `msdt.exe -id WindowsMediaPlayerConfigurationDiagnostic`, I tried removing and adding the music folder to the music library, I tried reinstalling Media Player - nothing helps.

What is intersting, though, that Media Player added the playlists I had in the folder, and also MP2 and MIDI files. Also if I play the files from the music folder manually, they appear in the library. But Media Player doesn't want to add all other files automatically.

I have WMP12 running on Windows 8 Professional 64-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me is as weird as the issue itself, but since I've already created the question, I'll provide the answer as well.

All I needed to do is to duplicate a file in the music folder and to remove it. After that Media Player started to add all other files. I have previously moved all the files to another folder and then brought them back, and that didn't help though, so the solution is even stranger.